# Born - Third person

Tags: word-usage

I am writing a staff announcement as the third person. One staff member says she is born in the city we are currently residing in.

Do I write

> She is born in Cape town

or

> She was born in Cape town

Comment: "was born" is correct, she is not born now.

Comment: born is always past unless it's science fiction.

Comment: @Lambie  Or sometimes when using it poetically/metaphorically, e.g. "May believes that the passion of the artist is born of the resistance to death of all kinds."  But in this context, yes, you're quite right.

Comment: @stangdon That is not the same context. **For the birth of people, it is always was born. All these useless pissing contests**.

Comment: You've put in the title "third person", but the grammar is identical in all persons.  "I was born in Portsmouth", "you were born in Paris", we were born in Madrid", etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's an event that happened in the past, so

> She **was** born in Cape **Town**.

However, we can use Present Simple for general statements

> They say that in China **a new baby is born** every five minutes.

or when telling stories

> Maggie is the victim of *the poverty* **she is born into** and, most tragically, cannot escape.

> When **she is born**, into a typical patriarchal family, her mother apologises to her mother-in-law for having a girl.

Comment: The present tense can be used in other cases apart from stories and general statements - it can be specific, e.g. "When your baby is born, let me know" or "If Jenna's baby is born next Thursday, his birthday will be the same as Michael's".